# How to implement my python code into tkinter gui code because nothing is working to stop the program because of multiple while loop runnning

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, screen-recording

I want to add this code into my tkinter gui code and i tried making it using command in buttons but the problem is, program wont stop running, it just freezes and i alrdy  tried things like `window.destroy(),exit()` but it just closes the window but exit doesnt quits me out of program until i press the stop button myself

**program code**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
screen_size = (1366, 768)
def recorder():
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    fps = 20.0
    output = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, fps, (screen_size))
    while True:
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        img_np = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        output.write(frame)
    output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can someone help me add the both code and without freezing the window....*I also tried threading but it didnt worked to stop the program.*

**tkinter gui code**

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x200+460+170")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.configure(bg='#030818')

Label(window, text="Recording", fg="white",bg="#030818",font=("Helvetica", 23, "bold")).pack()
Button(window, text="Start Recording", bd=0, bg="gray",fg="white",font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold")).place(x=170,y=60)
Button(window, text="Stop Recording", bd=0, bg="gray",fg="white",font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold")).place(x=170,y=110)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add a condition to break out of your while loop?

Comment: condition didnt work as well, or maybe i did it the wrong way but i tried it already

Comment: example which uses `root.after(milisecond, function)` instead of `while`-loop to display stream from `cv2` in `tkinter` - [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20with%20buttons%20to%20start%20and%20stop/main.py). It has also buttons to start and stop playing stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your code has never executed `recorder()` because you have not assigned any function to the two buttons.

Second you need to run `recorder()` in a thread so that it won't block tkinter `mainloop()`.

In order to stop the recording, you need to find a way to break out from the while loop.  Normally [threading.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) object is used in multi-threaded application.

Below are the required changes to achieve the goal:

```py
import threading
...

recording = threading.Event()  # flag used for breaking out the while loop

def recorder():
    print("recording started")
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
    fps = 20.0
    output = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, fps, screen_size)
    recording.set()  # set the recording flag
    while recording.is_set(): # keep running until recording flag is clear
        img = ImageGrab.grab().resize(screen_size)
        img_np = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        output.write(frame)
    output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("recording stopped")

def start_recording():
    # make sure only one recording thread is running
    if not recording.is_set():
        # start the recording task in a thread
        threading.Thread(target=recorder).start()

def stop_recording():
    # stop recording by clearing the flag
    recording.clear()

...
Button(window, text="Start Recording", command=start_recording, bd=0, bg="gray",fg="white",font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold")).place(x=170,y=60)
Button(window, text="Stop Recording", command=stop_recording, bd=0, bg="gray",fg="white",font=("Helvetica", 15, "bold")).place(x=170,y=110)
...
```

Comment: thx for your answer. I didnt uplaoded the code in which i had call the functions and used thread or tried all the other ways i knew but none of them worked and all my tries was a fail so i havent included that work here.i will try your solution.

Comment: thx for your solution, it worked perfectly fine. I didnt had idea about threading.Event or .set(), because i had only used threading few times before, if i had knew about that setting flag using threading i wouldnt been stuck in that thing for like 10 hours